# How to import __init__'s method in inner module?

Tags: python, import

My structure of file is

```
foo/
   __init__.py
   bar.py
```

file __init__.py

```
def abc():
    print 'ABC'
```

file bar.py

```
from foo import abc
```

I got this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "foo/bar.py", line 1, in <module>
   from foo import abc
ImportError: No module named foo
```

Comment: if i write `from __init__.py import abc` then its working is this okey ?

Comment: you should not use `abc` as a user module name because it already exists as a standard python module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a relative import (requires Python 2.6 or greater):

```
from . import abc
```

Comment: This produces the following: `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`.

Comment: Probably the `__init__.py` file is not saved to the disk. Using the relative imports is the best way to do internal imports in a package.

Comment: In Python3.5 it gives `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`

Comment: @MnemonicFlow: that is the equivalent of the old “`ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`”. You can only use it inside a package, e.g. the `foo/bar.py` of this question, not at the top level.

Answer (score 4):

Importing `foo` like that should work, but you need to ensure that the directory above `foo` is on the Python path. You can check what is on the path by printing `sys.path`.

If you give us more details on how you're running your code, including a full traceback on the error I can help more, but the basic advice is to check the Python path is correct.

Answer (score 1):

When importing the package, Python searches through the directories on `sys.path` looking for the package subdirectory. That means that`foo`must be a *subdirectory* of one of the directories in the`sys.path`list. Since`bar.py`is itself in the`foo`directory, one way this could be accomplished would be for it to add its parent folder to `sys.path` like this (assuming`foo`is the current working directory when it's executed):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')  # add parent folder

from foo import abc
```

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me, even if `bar.py` was imported in `__init__.py`:

```
from .__init__ import abc
```

There is one tiny downside of this though. When `abc` is type hinted, it will be noted in helps as `foo.__init__.abc` instead of `foo.abc`. As a workaround, this case I use string type hints like `def somefunc() -> 'foo.abc':`.